# 301 Redirect & site alias

Tags: http, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

so I have a site I want to take offline. developmentsite.com and I want to redirect to a new site.

So I do a 301 redirect.

Redirect 301 / http://www.newssite.con. Now I want to continue working on developmentsite.com so I set it up as an alias on my own site

mysite.developmentsite.com but because the .htaccess in the main httpdocs folder both sites redirect.

How can I stop the alias redirecting?

Thanks,

Ross

Answer (score 0):

You need mod_rewrite for this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# exclude the dev site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite\.developmentsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newssite.com/ [L,R=301]
```